# Multiple custom validation in angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript, validation, angular2-forms, angular-reactive-forms

I am facing a issue while adding multiple custom validation to a form. I can only add a single custom validation to my form. How to add multiple validations.

Eg:

```
this.user = this.fb.group({
  name: ['', Validators.required],
  account: this.fb.group({
    email: ['', Validators.required],
    confirm: ['', Validators.required]
  }, { validator: emailMatcher })
});
```

I want to add more validations like: { validator: [emailMatcher, matchPassword, othervalidation]}

Is there something in angular 2 which can help me in this.

Comment: or   email: ["", [Validators.required, this.validateService.emailValidator]]

Answer (score 3):

Instead of :

```
{ validator: emailMatcher })
```

Use syntax:

```
{ validators:  [emailMatcher, matchPassword, othervalidation]}
```

Good luck.

Comment: I think it should be 'validators' instead of 'Validators' because of https://angular.io/api/forms/FormBuilder#group

Comment: you're probably  @EmonZan  , not sure maybe the syntax changed from Angular 2 to current Angular 8, would need to bring out old Angular 2 project and test

Comment: @EmonZan If Gary doesn't edit the answer and you still think you are correct, please add your answer as a separate answer instead of changing significantly the Gary Holland answer.

Comment: I've modified to `validators`, as that is what the docs say.  However, the original syntax `Validators` does still appear to work (as of Angular 9).